# How to convert .WSQ FingerPrint Image File to .BMP FIle in C#

Tags: c#, fingerprinting

Is there a way to convert a .wsq fingerprint image file to a bitmap image (bmp) file?

sample .wsq fingerprint image file is here

http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?qbwy76rmc666dbr

Answer (score 2):

I once had to use a utility called iwsq to extract bitmap from a wsq file. Unfortunately, it was binary only, the source was unknown, and there was no source code.

Searching for iwsq brought up [this archive](http://www.math.wustl.edu/~victor/software/wsq/index.html) that you'd call as executable directly from c#.

There is also the [FFPIS project](http://ffpis.sourceforge.net/) on SourceForge. It has not been updated since 2004, but the links may provide more code.

[WSQ Image Library](http://www.cognaxon.com/index.php?page=wsqlibrary) is a WSQ-related SDK that comes with a price tag.

[NIST](http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nbis.cfm) also provides some [download material and source code](http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nigos.cfm).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JNBIS](http://code.google.com/p/jnbis/) for Java or [Wsq2Bmp](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/429481/Wsq-to-Bmp-converter) for .NET

Answer (score 1):

And I provide a .NET wrapper (encoding/deconding, Windows Forms and Wpf images) around the NBIS implementation here: https://github.com/odalet/Delta.Imaging/tree/master/Delta.Wsq

Answer (score 0):

We have implemented this utility (converting .WSQ fingerprint file into .BMP) in Java and made it available as a web service. You are free to use it: http://leversystems.com/products/fiss/. Sample code on how to use this service is also available in C# and Java.

Comment: do you still have it ?